# How can I overcome performance anxiety?

Tags: piano, performing

I've been playing for two years and performed a few times already. But recently I seem to forget whatever I'm playing when I get nervous in front of my teacher and small audiences.  Even if i practice multiple times perfectly beforehand, my hands don't know where to go and I end up playing wrong notes. It's as if I've never played it before. Is there any way to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

I found for myself, that playing with an "open mic" group of performers, helped me to get over playing in front of crowds. Go and listen to some in your area, to see if they play the same sort of music that you do. Ask to join in, when audience numbers are low, and then go from there.